# Laravel withCount on two models including constraints and global scope leads to query parameters getting out of order

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple one-to-many one-to-many relationship between three models.  Adding $withCount to the middle model, when there is a global scope on the bottom model is causing a strange parameter offset within the subselect query.

**Model 1 Top Level**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    public function bookings()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Booking');
    }
}
```

**Model 2 Middle Level**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Booking extends Model
{
    protected $withCount = ['extras'];  //This is causing the issue

    public function extras()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Extra');
    }
}
```

**Model 3 Bottom Level**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Extra extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('app', function(Builder $builder)
        {
            $builder->where('app_id', 1);
        });
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
use App\Event;

$events = Event::withCount([
    'bookings' => function($query){
        $query->where('status', 'open');
    }
])->get();
```

returns

```
select `events`.*,
(
  select count(*)
  from `bookings`
  where `events`.`id` = `bookings`.`event_id`
  and `status` = '1'
) as `bookings_count`
from `events`
```

removing the count on App\Booking gives

```
select `events`.*,
(
  select count(*)
  from `bookings`
  where `events`.`id` = `bookings`.`event_id`
  and `status` = 'open'
) as `bookings_count`
from `events`
```

as expected

Comment: this seems a laravel problem, i've created an issue and a patch on github, if you want using your code and fix the issue now, you can extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` class and apply my fix, make your relationships extend from new Relation class. ref: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21464